# How do I update Google Analytics session data using Measurement Protocol without creating a new session

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

QUESTION: How can I assure that the visitor's original session is updated/attributed with a new Goal triggered by using Measurement Protocol, even if the trigger happens after the original session window has expired?

**Problem in detail:**

1. I am capturing the cid from the _ga cookie when a visitor reaches my site and makes contact via a form
2. I then use that Measurement Protocol with the captured cid to send data back to Google Analytics to trigger a Goal "Client Registered" if that visitor later registers for my services.
3. If this happens within the 4 hour session window of the visitor's first visit to my site, then that session created with that first visit is attributed with the Goal.
4. HOWEVER, If I send the data to Google Analytics after the 4 hour session window, then Google Analytics sees my Measurement Protocol hit as a new session and creates a new session to which the Goal is attributed. But I want the original session to show the new Goal value.

I believe the following StackOverflow question is related, but has no answers posted:
"[Google analytics measurement protocol session timeout and query time limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753183/google-analytics-measurement-protocol-session-timeout-and-query-time-limits)"

Answer (score 1):

Nope, this is not possible, what you can do is make the hit non-interactive. As can be found in the parameter reference; https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ni
But from the testing I did I found out that GA looks at goal date which can't be changed.